# I have a yahoo and a google (Gmail) account

Tags: google-contacts

I always have used the yahoo account but don't remember the gmail account password. If the two accounts are linked, will I delete both if i delete one of them? Where could I locate the place where I could change/create the gmail account? It might be useful to have 2 email addresses
Sincerest of thanks for any guidance you could offer...
Stan

Answer (score 0):

Deleting one account won't affect the other one(s).

On Android 4.x you can head to **Settings** (the gray gear icon app), then scroll down to **Accounts** and tap **+ Add account**. You'll then be able to select which type of account you want to add (some of the possible options are *Corporate*, *Email*, *Exchange* and *Google*). If e.g. you want to add a new Gmail, select *Google* account and proceed. You'll be required to inform if you wish to add a *New* Google account or set up an *Existing* one. Tap *New* and proceed.

Once you've added your new Google account, you can e.g. access the **People** app (the one that gives access to all your contacts), then tap the button having 3 vertically aligned dots on the lower right corner:

[image: 3-dot button]

...so you can tap **Accounts** to select your accounts and what you want to sync on each one (e.g. sync contacts). There will also be a **Contacts to display** option, which gives you the option to choose which contacts (from which accounts) you want displayed by the **People** app.